# MYSQL - Get rows in one table having multiple rows in another table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables in one database:

Properties table:

```
+-------------+--------------------+
| property_id | property_reference |
+-------------+--------------------+
|           1 | RA123              |
|           4 | RT123              |
+-------------+--------------------+
```

Features table:

```
+------------+--------------+
| feature_id | feature_name |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 | pool         |
|          2 | garden       |
|          3 | wine house   |
|          4 | parking      |
+------------+--------------+
```

And one table properties_features:

```
+-------------+------------+
| property_id | feature_id |
+-------------+------------+
|           1 |          1 |
|           1 |          2 |
|           1 |          4 |
|           4 |          1 |
|           4 |          2 |
|           4 |          3 |
+-------------+------------+
```

And for example I want to retrieve the properties id's that have pool and garden only

Comment: looking to your sample seems that you have not product that have pool and garden only

Comment: @scaisEdge yea there is, property_id 1 and 4 both have pool and garden if you look at the properties_features table

Comment: @turner  property_id 1 have feature_id 1,2,4  (pool, garden and parking )

Comment: @scaisEdge ahh just noticed he said only

Comment: Alrighty I have an answer for you, one moment

Comment: @scaisEdge You are right, I made the question in a wrong way. I wanted to know the properties that have pool and garden

Comment: @PedroCosta  anyway  seems that you have alredy an accepted  answer ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct property_id  from properties_features
where feature_id  IN (1,2) and property_id  in(select property_id  from properties_features where feature_id  IN(1,2) group by property_id  having COUNT(property_id ) > 1)
order by property_id
```

This will get all of the Property ID's that are having a pool and garden without any joins or hard coded data.

This will help you out in the future too if any feature_name is changed, for example: from pool -> Pool. This query will still work! :)

It's a good practice to not use any hard coded values for more dynamic querys.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
    select property_id 
    from properties_features left join Features 
    on properties_features.feature_id = Features.feature_id
    where properties_features.feature_id in 
      (select feature_id
          from Features 
         where feature_name in ('pool', 'garden'))
    group by property_id 
    having count(distinct properties_features.feature_id)>1
```

Here's a working sqlfiddle:

```
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcbc5b7/3
```